# Custom XML encoder with Axis 1 and Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss, axis

The documentation on [this](http://axis.apache.org/axis/java/integration-guide.html) page indicates that I can override Axis's default XML encoder by providing a file with this path:

```
myapp.war/META-INF/services/org.apache.axis.components.encoding.XMLEncoder
```

The file contents of this file are:

```
com.myapp.CustomEncoder
```

Where com.myapp.Customer is in myapp.war/WEB-INF/classes/com/myapp/CustomEncoder.class.

Note that myapp.war is actually exploded as a full directory when I deploy but I don't think that should make a difference.

In any case, this doesn't seem to work on Apache Tomcat 7.0 but strangely enough does work on JBoss 4.2.3. Alternatively I tried setting a system property by adding this to Tomcat's startup script:

```
-Dorg.apache.axis.components.encoding.XMLEncoder=com.myapp.CustomEncoder
```

Still not seeing my CustomEncoder code being called, and only on Tomcat. Why should this work on JBoss and not Tomcat? Is the classpath different somehow on Tomcat? How can I make this work?

Thanks.

---- Update ----

Since it was mentioned, the source code that seems to load the custom provider appears to exist in org.apache.axis.components.encoding.XMLEncoderFactory:

```
public static final String ENCODING_UTF_8 = "UTF-8";
public static final String ENCODING_UTF_16 = "UTF-16";
public static final String DEFAULT_ENCODING = ENCODING_UTF_8;

private static Map encoderMap = new HashMap();
private static final String PLUGABLE_PROVIDER_FILENAME = "org.apache.axis.components.encoding.XMLEncoder";

static {
    encoderMap.put(ENCODING_UTF_8, new UTF8Encoder());
    encoderMap.put(ENCODING_UTF_16, new UTF16Encoder());
    encoderMap.put(ENCODING_UTF_8.toLowerCase(), new UTF8Encoder());
    encoderMap.put(ENCODING_UTF_16.toLowerCase(), new UTF16Encoder());
    try {
        loadPluggableEncoders();
    } catch (Throwable t){
        String msg=t + JavaUtils.LS + JavaUtils.stackToString(t);
        log.info(Messages.getMessage("exception01",msg));
    }
}

...

/**
 Look for file META-INF/services/org.apache.axis.components.encoding.XMLEncoder
 in all the JARS, get the classes listed in those files and add them to 
 encoders list if they are valid encoders. 

 Here is how the scheme would work.

 A company providing a new encoder will jar up their encoder related
 classes in a JAR file. The following file containing the name of the new 
 encoder class is also made part of this JAR file. 

 META-INF/services/org.apache.axis.components.encoding.XMLEncoder

 By making this JAR part of the webapp, the new encoder will be 
 automatically discovered. 
 */
private static void loadPluggableEncoders() {
    ClassLoader clzLoader = XMLEncoder.class.getClassLoader();
    ClassLoaders loaders = new ClassLoaders();
    loaders.put(clzLoader);
    DiscoverServiceNames dsn = new DiscoverServiceNames(loaders);
    ResourceNameIterator iter = dsn.findResourceNames(PLUGABLE_PROVIDER_FILENAME);
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        String className = iter.nextResourceName();
        try {
            Object o = Class.forName(className).newInstance();
            if (o instanceof XMLEncoder) {
                XMLEncoder encoder = (XMLEncoder) o;
                encoderMap.put(encoder.getEncoding(), encoder);
                encoderMap.put(encoder.getEncoding().toLowerCase(), encoder);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            String msg = e + JavaUtils.LS + JavaUtils.stackToString(e);
            log.info(Messages.getMessage("exception01", msg));
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Just for fun, I tried packaging up META-INF/services/org.apache.axis.components.encoding.XMLEncoder in a separate jar and storing it in myapp.war/WEB-INF/lib; still nothing.

I don't get it.

Comment: I guess you will have to step through the source of Axis.

Comment: Updated with axis code that appears to be responsible for loading this. It's still not clear to me what's going on though.

Answer (score 1):

make new project say encoder which contain your custom encoder then make it jar.Under jar under meta -inf create services folder and under it create file org.apache.axis.components.encoding.XMLEncoder and in this file mention your class name of your encoder (fully qualified) .place this jar in your class path .